# libc6 failed Bionic upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 18.04

While upgrading from Xenial to Bionic on a VPS server based on a 64bit, I get the following error:

> ```
> Could not install the upgrades    
> The upgrade has aborted. Your system could be in an unusable state. 
> A recovery will run now (dpkg --configure -a).
>
> dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libc-bin:
>  libc-bin depends on libc6 (>> 2.27); however:
>   Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.23-0ubuntu10.
>
> dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--configure):
>  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
> Errors were encountered while processing:
>  libc-bin
>
> Upgrade incomplete  
> The upgrade has partially completed but there were errors during the
> upgrade process.
> ```

I tried almost everything I could google but nothing works:

> ```
> You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>  libc6 : Breaks: libc6:i386 (!= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.23-0ubuntu10 is to be installed
>  libc6:i386 : Breaks: libc6 (!= 2.23-0ubuntu10) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
>  libc6-amd64:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.23-0ubuntu10 is to be installed
> E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
> ```

If I try `apt-get -f install` I get :

> ```
>  Configuring libc6 tqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqk
>    x                                                                       x
>    x Kernel must be upgraded                                               x
>    x                                                                       x
>    x This version of the GNU libc requires kernel version 3.2 or later.    x
>    x Please upgrade your kernel before installing glibc.                   x
>    x                                                                       x
>    x                                <Ok>                                   x
>    x                                                                       x
>    mqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqj
> ```

And i´m in a loop.

Is there any solution to this failed upgrade?

Comment: I have this problem too.

Comment: I belive this is a OpenVZ issue when OS templates are old. I was on a cheap VPS server with old OS templates that dont suport a recent kernel. I don´t know how to solve that without changing to a new hosting company.

Comment: Have you contacted their support?